# Extra space added at the end of req.params.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When trying to request the id I'm having this error pop up:

```
const castError = new CastError();.
stringValue: '"6317861ce9acfa3f2d2101a3 "',
kind: 'ObjectId',
value: '6317861ce9acfa3f2d2101a3 ',
path: '_id',
```

I believe this error is popping up because there is an extra space at the end of the ID but have no idea why the space is being added. If more code is needed to find the solution to this error let me know.

```html
router.put('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    req.article = await Article.findById(req.params.id);
    next();
}, saveArticleAndRedirect('edit'))
```

Comment: Check your api url, it seems you are putting a space at the end of the url, be sure there is no space

Comment: If it's just because of an space you can solve it with `Article.findById(req.params.id.trim())`.